# TabWidget aligned on the bottom overlaps other Views

Tags: android, android-layout, tabwidget

I have `TabWidget` that is aligned on the bottom of the page. I can't get it to not overlap other views. More specifically it overlaps my `FrameLayout`. I need `FrameLayout` to adjust its height to `TabWidget` so that both views don't overlap each other. How can I fix the code below to achieve this result?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF"
    tools:context="pl.holdapp.slf.activities.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_above="@android:id/tabcontent" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Your FrameLayout has layout_height set to fill_parent, change this value avoiding fill the parent layout(RelativeLayout) that is the same that contain your tabWidget;)

Comment: @axlcoder: Ok, but I don't get what to change it to so that the height of FrameLayout adjusts to TabWidget so that both fill RelativeLayout without overlapping each other. Should that be some fixed size in dp?

Comment: Yes, IMHO the best way is to set fixed size in dp, otherwise you can set that your tabWidget is aligned after your FrameLayout with android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tabcontent".

Comment: @axlcoder Well, I gave my RelativeLayout marginBottom and obviously it works. It just doesn't seem like a pretty solution :/

Comment: Have you tried android:layout_alignBottom?

Comment: @axlcoder: Yes, I just tried and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your FrameLayout with the id `@android:id/tabcontent`, include the following attributes:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```

Comment: When I do so I get: "@+id/viewPager is not a sibling in the same 
 RelativeLayout".

Comment: Now I get: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout"

Comment: Remove `android:layout_above="@android:id/tabcontent"` from the TabWidget

Comment: Yes, I tried that but still no luck :( For now, I am gonna go for fixed dp bottom margin for FrameLayout I guess.

Comment: Alternatively you can try a vertical `LinearLayout`